# How to read Android 10 devices files with Flutter App

Tags: android, file, flutter, dart, local-storage

Am using this code to try to read a particular directory an android devices.. this is the code in a released application. it works fine on all devices except SamSung devices..

```
fetchFromOriginalDirectory() async{
    var result = await PhotoManager.requestPermission();//getting permission to check files
   if (result) {
      Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/');


List<FileSystemEntity> _files;

_files = dir.listSync(recursive: true, followLinks: false).reversed.toList();//getting all files(stickers) in this directory
for(FileSystemEntity entity in _files) {//for each file gotten do this
  String path = entity.path;
```

I first thought the problem was this line  "/storage/emulated/0/" but after using multiple plugins to check for the right path. i found out the paths are the same. But for some reason the app cant read the files on samsung files. even after all permissions have been granted

Comment: Are you saying the issue is particular to Samsung devices and app works properly on other devices? /storage/emulated/0/ is meant to be the device storage.

Comment: i just found out it is not for samsung it is for android 10 devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey guys i fixed it by doing this

```
 <application
       
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" //adding this line
        >
```

In the android manifest file.